# How to process scala dataframe in chunks in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have a huge dataframe in scala of around 120000 rows. We want to process the dataframe into chunks of 25 each and do 1 http request for 25 rows together as we divide. What is the best way  to divide the dataframe and do some operations on each chunk.

For Example:

Consider this dataframe `val df = Seq((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)).toDF()`
and let's suppose we want to first take 4 rows and perform some operation on those, then next 4 perform operation on them and then perform operation on remaining 2

Answer (score 0):

You could `repartition` your dataframe to chop it up in the size that you want, and then use `foreachPartition` to do a certain operation on each of these partitions.

On your small example, it could look something like the following:

```
val df = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10).toDF().repartition(3)

df.rdd.foreachPartition(iterator => {
    println(s"printing: ${iterator.mkString(",")}")
})

printing: [1],[3],[8]
printing: [5],[7],[9]
printing: [2],[4],[6],[10]
```

In here, we're using `.repartition(3)` to chop up our dataset in the desired size. Note that in this case the size of our partitions is 3 or 4 (since 10 is not a multiple of 4).

So in your case, you simply have to:

- change `.repartition(3)` to `.repartition(4800)` (120000/25 = 4800)
- change the `println(s"printing: ${iterator.mkString(",")}")` line to whatever operation you want to be doing